# Shorter OOP writing of javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have a little experience in javascript/jQuery coding but still in the "normal" and sometimes largest way. I have some code that i have duplicated for 2 seperate groups in my form. This javascript code make it possible to build dynamic input fields (add input field or remove). I just think that i could do it in a more dynamic way (same code for the 2 groups) so my code could be shorter. I am in learning fase and could use a hand with this shorter writing. I have bought myself a book of OOP but i don't really understand in my example where i have to call my instance? So my question would be who could help me on the way?

Original javascript code:

```
var MAX_OPTIONS = 10;
//  Add button click handler on Location 
        .on('click', '.addLocation', function() {
            var $template = $('#optionLocation'),
                $clone    = $template
                                .clone()
                                .removeClass('hide')
                                .removeAttr('id')
                                .insertBefore($template),
                $option   = $clone.find('[name="locatie[]"]');

            // Add new field
            $('#surveyForm').bootstrapValidator('addField', $option);
        })

        // Remove button click handler
        .on('click', '.removeLocation', function() {
            var $row    = $(this).parents('.form-group'),
                $option = $row.find('[name="locatie[]"]');

            // Remove element containing the option
            $row.remove();

            // Remove field
            $('#surveyForm').bootstrapValidator('removeField', $option);
        })

        // Called after adding new field
        .on('added.field.bv', function(e, data) {
            // data.field   --> The field name
            // data.element --> The new field element
            // data.options --> The new field options

            if (data.field === 'locatie[]') {
                if ($('#surveyForm').find(':visible[name="locatie[]"]').length >= MAX_OPTIONS) {
                    $('#surveyForm').find('.addLocation').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        })

        // Called after removing the field
        .on('removed.field.bv', function(e, data) {
           if (data.field === 'locatie[]') {
                if ($('#surveyForm').find(':visible[name="locatie[]"]').length < MAX_OPTIONS) {
                    $('#surveyForm').find('.addLocation').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            }
        })


// Add button click handler on Reason 
        .on('click', '.addReason', function() {
            var $template = $('#optionReason'),
                $clone    = $template
                                .clone()
                                .removeClass('hide')
                                .removeAttr('id')
                                .insertBefore($template),
                $option   = $clone.find('[name="reden[]"]');

            // Add new field
            $('#surveyForm').bootstrapValidator('addField', $option);
        })

        // Remove button click handler
        .on('click', '.removeReason', function() {
            var $row    = $(this).parents('.form-group'),
                $option = $row.find('[name="reden[]"]');

            // Remove element containing the option
            $row.remove();

            // Remove field
            $('#surveyForm').bootstrapValidator('removeField', $option);
        })

        // Called after adding new field
        .on('added.field.bv', function(e, data) {
            // data.field   --> The field name
            // data.element --> The new field element
            // data.options --> The new field options

            if (data.field === 'reden[]') {
                if ($('#surveyForm').find(':visible[name="reden[]"]').length >= MAX_OPTIONS) {
                    $('#surveyForm').find('.addReason').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            }
        })

        // Called after removing the field
        .on('removed.field.bv', function(e, data) {
           if (data.field === 'reden[]') {
                if ($('#surveyForm').find(':visible[name="reden[]"]').length < MAX_OPTIONS) {
                    $('#surveyForm').find('.addReason').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            }
        });                
});
```

My form group of location:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-11">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="locatie[]" placeholder="Aanmeldpunt" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addLocation">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group hide" id="optionLocation">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-11">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="locatie[]" placeholder="Aanmeldpunt" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeLocation">
                                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My form group of Reason:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control reason1" name="reden[]" id="reason1" placeholder="Reden" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <input type="file" name="redenafb[]" id="reasonImg1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <input type="time" class="form-control reasonTime1" name="readentijd[]" id="reasonTime1" placeholder="480" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addReason">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>                            
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group hide" id="optionReason">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control reason2" name="reden[]" id="reason2" placeholder="Reden" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <input type="file" name="readenafb[]" id="reasonImg2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <input type="time" class="form-control reasonTime2" name="readentijd[]" id="reasonTime2" placeholder="480" />
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeReason">
                            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>                            
                </div>                    
            </div>
```

Comment: Pretty much all the big JavaScript frameworks are designed to solve the problem of jQuery spaghetti code. Consider looking at Ember or Angular.

Comment: @meagar , he wants to improve his logic, and it can be done using custom coding only

Comment: Your JS (actually jQ) is not valid. You *cannot* start simply with `.on()` without referencing to the jQuery object selector.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I did not post all of the code. There is a Validation on that same form before where i reference to. But it is just this code i want to get smaller.